# Proving $(x + y, z - 1)$ and $(x - z^2, y + z) \subseteq k[x,y,z]$ as ideals are radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Having a hard time thinking of how to tackle this. It's part 1 of a much longer assignment. Hints before outright solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Compute the quotient. Both ideals are even prime.

Comment: I know intuitively that they're prime, and prime => radical, but I don't know how to show they're prime.

Comment: As I said: Compute the quotient.

Comment: If you know the Nullstellensatz, you could consider the fact that an ideal $I$ is prime if and only if the corresponding algebraic subset $Z(I)$ is irreducible. Assuming $k$ is a field, you could also try the linked question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501275/is-the-ideal-generated-by-an-irreducible-polynomial-prime/816406.

Comment: @AnCoileanach That does not help at all, since the irreducibility of $Z(I)$ does only show that $\sqrt I$ is prime. And we want to show that $\sqrt I =I$.

Comment: @MooS, sorry you're totally right, my bad. I can delete my comment if you think it will only muddy the waters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some start-help on how to compute the quotient of the second ideal.

First observe that one of the generators is linear. This *always* means that we can eliminate one of the variables:

$$
k[x,y,z]/(x-z^2,y+z) \stackrel{y \mapsto -z}{\simeq} k[x,z]/(x-z^2)
$$

Here we eliminated $y$, since in the quotient we have that $y \equiv -z$.

Do you see how you an also eliminate $x$?